# PHP For Loop Optimation

Tags: php, for-loop

If I have a simple case,
example:

> How Many times, number 7 appears between number 1 until 1000000000?

This is my code:

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$counter = 0;
$counter_num = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1000000000; $i++) {
    if (substr_count($i, '7') > 0) {
        $counter = $counter + substr_count($i, '7');
        $counter_num++;
    }
    if ($i % 1000000 == 0) {
        echo 'Until ' . $i . "<br/>";
        echo "So Far: " . $counter;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo "Appears: " . $counter_num;
        echo '<br/>';
        $time_end = microtime(true);
        $execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start) / 60;
        echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> ' . $execution_time . ' Mins';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<hr/>';
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my logic?
I try it using apple macbook pro core i5, ram 8gb bootcamp windows 7.
This is the last result..

```
Until 1000000000 So Far: 900000000 Appears: 612579511 Total Execution Time: 129.54485953252 Mins
```

It means 2 hours..
How to optimize this loop?
I am just looking answer how to optimize the loop, does not matter using php, c#, javascript or whatever coding language.

Comment: Why would you use string manipulation to find that 7 and not some tricky math formulas that you can easily find over math forum of stackexchange

Comment: dont use a loop is the best way. How many times does a 7 appear between 1 and 10 ? what about 1 and 20 ? 1 and 100 ? When you see the patten you dont need to loop. if you STILL want to use a loop `substr_count($i, '7')` needs to be called once, not twice as it is currently

Comment: exussum is correct.. is there another way? to make optimation?

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a good *direction* :)

```
<?php
    $from=0;
    $to=999999999;
    $numbers=$to-$from;
    echo ceil((strlen($to)*$numbers)/10);    // 900000000 times
?>
```

Think of `00 to 999`, how many numbers are those total? 1000. There are 3 digits for each number. Hence a total of 3000 digits. In a series, all digits will be represented equal number of times and there are 10 total being used. So 3000/10 = 300 times a 7 or a 6 or a 5 was used.

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/230873)**

P.S: I know your actual requirement is more than that. This shows in how many numbers a 7 was used, doesn't show how many 7's are there exactly. But since your solution is way too brute force, you can take a hint from here and build upon it.

**[Inspiration](http://gmatclub.com/forum/how-many-times-7-in-1000-gmatclub-m01-99007.html)**

Answer (score 0):

like the others said calling 2 times substr_count doesnt make any sense.
I did the same thing as rosscowar except i didnt change the for() and add a break in exchange and the code is 0.5s faster then his with 10000000 tries (at least on my machine).

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);
$counter_num = 0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000000; $i++) {
    $counter_num += substr_count($i, '7');
    if ($i % 1000000 == 0) {
        echo 'Until ' . $i . "<br/>";
        echo "So Far: $i<br/>Appears: $counter_num<br/>";
        $execution_time = (microtime(true) - $time_start) / 60;
        echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> ' . $execution_time . ' Mins';
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<hr/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `$counter` needs to contain the total number of 7's and `$counter_num` contains how many numbers contributed to that total. Your `$counter` will remain unchanged the whole time.

Comment: i forget that, i changed to $i, so its the same, no need for $counter at all